# WPF ContentControl not displaying anything

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, contentcontrol

I am trying to build a Control that selectively displays different things based upon the types that are passed in, but for some reason I end up displaying nothing at all.

Is there some fundamental thing that I am missing here? (This code is massively stripped down from my real production app bu exhibits the same behavior)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new List<ContactInformation>
            {
                new Address {Street = "21 Jump", City = "Sparta", State = "Denial"},
                new Phone {Number = "734-555-1212"}
            };
    }
}

public class ContactInformation
{
}

public class Address : ContactInformation
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class Phone : ContactInformation
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

<Window x:Class="ContentControlExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:contentControlExample="clr-namespace:ContentControlExample"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding /}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding /}" Content="{Binding /}">
                        <ContentControl.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type contentControlExample:Address}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Street}"/>
                                    <TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
                                                <Binding Path="City"/>
                                                <Binding Path="State"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type contentControlExample:Phone}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContentControl.Resources>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I don't know what `"{Binding /}"` means, but I don't use that. Simply change that to `"{Binding}"`.

Comment: I've never seen bindings use a `/` like you have... perhaps that's related? A quick way of testing would be to just move your DataTemplates to `<Window.Resources>` and leave your `ItemsControl` as `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }" />`. By default an `ItemsControl` already draws your item with a `ContentPresenter`, and should use your implicit templates to draw each item. If that doesn't work, check out your visual tree and it's `DataContext` with a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and that will probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: / means the current item of a collection, so <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding /}"> would mean the current item of the ContactInformation list. You don't need the other /'s though.

Comment: @Phil If that's the case, then the problem is probably because the current item doesn't have a "current item" property, so "/" doesn't work for the nested bindings. I'm sure there are some binding errors being outputted that could point out the exact problem location :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to remove a couple of '/' as follow:

```
XAML:

<Window x:Class="ContentControlExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:contentControlExample="clr-namespace:ContentControlExample"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding }" Content="{Binding }">
                        <ContentControl.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type contentControlExample:Address}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Street}"/>
                                    <TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
                                                <Binding Path="City"/>
                                                <Binding Path="State"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type contentControlExample:Phone}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContentControl.Resources>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Code behind:

```
namespace ContentControlExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new List<ContactInformation>
            {
                new Address {Street = "21 Jump", City = "Sparta", State = "Denial"},
                new Phone {Number = "734-555-1212"}
            };
        }
    }

    public class ContactInformation
    {
    }

    public class Address : ContactInformation
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }

    public class Phone : ContactInformation
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Ouput:

[image: Result]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure what the difference that I had was, but that gave me the working pieces I needed thanks.

Comment: @Matt I am trying to get a XamDataGrid field to use a ContentControl that I set the ContentTemplate  based on value and having the same result as you, nothing appears.  No error, but no grid either.  I have it all working in a standard WPF DataGrid.  But can not make it work in the XamDataGrid.  I can't see anything in this post that will make it work.  Can you tell me how you got it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your code slightly. This works because the `ItemsControl` automatically picks the correct `DataTemplate` based on the type of the item being bound to.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new List<ContactInformation>
                         {
                             new Address
                                 {
                                     Street = "21 Jump", 
                                     City = "Sparta", 
                                     State = "Denial"
                                 }, 
                             new Phone { Number = "734-555-1212" }
                         };
    }

    public List<ContactInformation> Items { get; set; }
}

<Window.DataContext>
    <contentControlExample:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type contentControlExample:Address}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Street}"/>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
                            <Binding Path="City"/>
                            <Binding Path="State"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type contentControlExample:Phone}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
</Grid>
```

Or to bind the current item to a content control:

```
<Grid>
    ... resources

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Items/}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I will try pulling the items out on a view model. The real production code isn't using a items control. What I am really doing is populating a single cell of a Infragistics XamDataGrid. The ItemsControl was exhibiting the same behavior that is why I used it as an example.

Comment: As best I can see your code does not display any different results from mine. Everything is still empty